# May <?xml... > be the first line of an dtd?

Tags: xml, dtd

May the line  be the first line of an external dtd? I had an argue about that, but we couldn't find a source like dtd language specification to get the solution.

Comment: No it can't, because a DTD is not valid XML.  It can be the first line in an .xsd schema, because it is XML.  Schemas came after DTDs during the development of XML once the deficiency was noted.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp

Comment: Yeah, more or less this is what we got, but is there some official language specification?

Comment: @duffymo - Sure it can. See my answer for the reason why.

Comment: Can't imagine why one would do so.  DTD != XML  No root tag.

Comment: @duffymo - It does make it easy to identify that it is an XML DTD and not an SGML DTD. Otherwise you might end up having to inspect element declarations to find out whether or not tag minimization is present (or contains inclusions/exclusions, etc.).

Comment: I'm ignorant;  never used SGML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can. It's not required though (even in an [XML 1.1 DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-extSubset)).

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd):

> **Well-formedness constraint: External Subset**
>
> The external subset, if any, must match the production for extSubset.

The spec defines [`extSubset`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-extSubset) as:

```
[30]  extSubset        ::=      TextDecl? extSubsetDecl 
[31]  extSubsetDecl    ::=      ( markupdecl | conditionalSect | DeclSep)*
```

and [`TextDecl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-TextDecl) (which is allowed to occur zero or once per definition above) as:

```
[77]  TextDecl         ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo? EncodingDecl S? '?>'
```